# Beautiful Soup Nested Tag Search

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a python program that will count the words on a web page. I use Beautiful Soup 4 to scrape the page but I have difficulties accessing nested HTML tags (for example: `<p class="hello">` inside `<div>`).

Every time I try finding such tag using `page.findAll()` (page is Beautiful Soup object containing the whole page) method it simply doesn't find any, although there are. Is there any simple method or another way to do it?

Comment: Please show some code you've tried. And the page you're trying to scrape.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Maybe I'm guessing what you are trying to do is first looking in a specific div tag and the search all p tags in it and count them or do whatever you want. For example:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser') 

# This will get the div
div_container = soup.find('div', class_='some_class')  

# Then search in that div_container for all p tags with class "hello"
for ptag in div_container.find_all('p', class_='hello'):
    # prints the p tag content
    print(ptag.text)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: What if between `<div class="someclass">` and `<p class='hello">` there are other tags like `<div>` or `<span>`?

Comment: @Heinz In your case if <p> has "class" then it's not a problem, but if you mean "<p>" is nested deeply in "divs" and "spans" which don't have any classes or static id's which you can use then you can recursively do it until you reach desired <p>. It's very case specific.

Comment: @Heinz you can do something like this in this situation ```resp.find('a').find('p').find('span').text``` hope this can help you because I was searching something similar and ended with this

Answer (score 3):

Try this one :

```
data = []
for nested_soup in soup.find_all('xyz'):
    data = data + nested_soup.find_all('abc')
```

**Maybe you can turn in into lambda and make it cool, but this works. Thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: I noticed that text does not always return the expected result, at the same time, I realized there was a built-in way to get the text, sure enough reading [the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) 
we read that there is a method called get_text(), use it as:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
fd = open('index.html', 'r')
website= fd.read()
fd.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(website)
contents= soup.get_text(separator=" ")
print "number of words %d" %len(contents.split(" "))
```

**INCORRECT, please read above**.Supposing that you have your html file locally in index.html you can:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
BLACKLIST = ["html", "head", "title", "script"] # tags to be ignored
fd = open('index.html', 'r')
website= fd.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(website)
tags=soup.find_all(True) # find everything
print "there are %d" %len(tags)

count= 0
matcher= re.compile("(\s|\n|<br>)+")
for tag in tags:
if tag.name.lower() in BLACKLIST:
    continue
    temp = matcher.split(tag.text) # Split using tokens such as \s and \n
    temp = filter(None, temp) # remove empty elements in the list
    count +=len(temp)
print "number of words in the document %d" %count
fd.close()
```

Please note that it may not be accurate, maybe because of errors in formatting, false positives(it detects any word, even if it is code), text that is shown dynamically using javascript or css, or other reason

Comment: Thanks you, but I am looking to count only some on the text, the text in <div> tags from a specific class, and not all the text on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all `<p>` tags using regular expressions (re module).
Note that `r.content` is a string which contains the whole html of the site.

for eg:

```
 r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
 p_tags = re.findall(r'<p>.*?</p>',r.content)
```

this should get you all the `<p>` tags irrespective of whether they are nested or not. And if you want the a tags specifically inside the  tags you can add that whole tag as a string in the second argument instead of `r.content`.

**Alternatively** if you just want just the text you can try this:

```
from readability import Document #pip install readability-lxml
import requests
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
doc = Document(r.content)
simplified_html = doc.summary()
```

this will get you a more bare bones form of the html from the site, and now proceed with the parsing.