# compare lists and see if part of element in one list exists in element in another list

Tags: python, html, list

I have a question. I'm parsing a website with Beautiful soup and adding some html tags and their contents to two different lists granted on the conditions they satisfy. Anyway, I have two lists,

```
name = [<a class="name-link" href="/shop/tops-sweaters/wxyvjbwed/emon78ji2">Vertical Logo Baseball Jersey</a>, <a class="name-link" href="/shop/tops-sweaters/wxyvjbwed/q2j1gm57b">Vertical L
ogo Baseball Jersey</a>, <a class="name-link" href="/shop/tops-sweaters/wxyvjbwed/ulovwdkr3">Vertical Logo Baseball Jersey</a>]
```

and

```
color = [<a class="name-link" href="/shop/tops-sweaters/wxyvjbwed/emon78ji2">Red</a>, <a class="name-link" href="/shop/tops-sweaters/noh7spfz2/kg3lseuzf">Red</a>, <a class="name-link" href="
/shop/tops-sweaters/p98rptfuw/a52kgnw0j">Red</a>, <a class="name-link" href="/shop/tops-sweaters/jxupqcv7o/vbj8g1f7u">Red</a>, <a class="name-link" href="/shop/tops-sweaters/gxfe5iqz
b/ulw54cqk3">Red</a>]
```

There is a set of matching hrefs between these two lists. I do not know what that href value is before I make the lists. Is there any html library or something built into python that could help solve my problem here? Here is the matching href between the lists as well, "/shop/tops-sweaters/wxyvjbwed/emon78ji2" . This should be the output

EDIT: Here is the html structure. The h1 tag surrounds the  tag.

```
<h1><a class="name-link" href="/shop/tops-sweaters/wxyvjbwed/emon78ji2">Vertical Logo Baseball Jersey</a></h1>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: "/shop/tops-sweaters/wxyvjbwed/emon78ji2" is the expected output. or href="/shop/tops-sweaters/wxyvjbwed/emon78ji2". That is the similar href between the two lists

Comment: I would still use `beautiful soup`, check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815747/beautifulsoup-getting-href

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using Beautiful Soup to find the `a` tags why not just pull the href values when you have the objects.  For example:

```
list = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
```

If you make each list a list of hrefs instead of the entire tag you can compare them easier.

```
matching = set(list1) & set(list2)
```

Comment: hmmm that may work. But I had already performed a find_all() on my soup object for a h1 tag. The <a> tag and its attributes are nested inside of there. Please take a look at my edit for notation and correct me if I am wrong, but you cannot call find() on a soup object that has already had find_all() called on it.

Comment: Something like the answer here helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510966/beautiful-soup-nested-tag-search but I can't originally call find_all() on soup or I get an AttributeError: AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: nevermind. I got it. I'm an idiot and it's late. thanks