# How do I get the second div element from request

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, request

HTML code

```
<div class="f_fs13">
                    <div class="bg_blue">first</div>
                    <div>range 5</div>
                        <div>
```

My code

```
race = page_soup.find_all("div",{"class":"f_fs13"})
```

I want to get the text of second div element(range 5)
Any quick way to get second div element

```
race = page_soup.find_all("div",{"class":"f_fs13 margin_top15"},[1]) #but not working
```

Comment: can't you simply use document.getElementsByClassName('bg_blue')[0] ?

Comment: how about `page_soup.select('.f_fs13 div:nth-child(2)')`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup Nested Tag Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510966/beautiful-soup-nested-tag-search)

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting desired output using css selector as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<div class="f_fs13"><div class="bg_blue">first</div><div>range 5</div>
                        
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify())

p= soup.select_one('div.f_fs13 div:nth-child(2)')
print(p.text)
```

Output:

```
range 5
```